# C++ Builder XE: find out where a specific h file is included

Tags: c++builder

I'm currently porting a rather big project from C++ Builder 5 to the newest version, C++ Builder XE. It's my first experience with C++ Builder. I'm stuck with an error in a file, but I don't want to include this file anyway (it's code of a component not required anymore). I was not able to find out where and how this file is included, however. The compiler error does not give any hint at all apart from the error itself. How do you usually find out where a file is included?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The preprocessor is perfect for this. Right click on the cpp file which gives you the error  in the project manager then choose "preprocess"
The output from this tells you every file and line number in the order they are processed. You can then search for the file in question, and the line above it is the file that included it.
This could conceivably be another header file as well, so it could be a long chain, but you can determine exactly where it comes from.

Comment: Hm, I tried that, but I can't find the file that causes the error within the output. Why could that be? I know that the file that eventually causes the error is included in the file I want to compile indirectly through a chain of five other headers - but I can't even find the second one of this chain within the output.

Comment: If you are preprocessing the correct cpp file, the exact file and line from your error message should be in the .i file. You should be able to search for problemheader.h: 999 if that is where the error message points to.

Answer (score 1):

If the files in question are rather sizable, a tool like [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) can be helpful in showing you the include dependencies (as well as call paths, etc.).

If it's just once or twice you'll have to do this, David Dean's suggestion of the preprocessor is golden.

Comment: I already thought about Doxygen too, since we already use it. Only problem is: the files I want to get rid of are external ones (from various components), so you can't see at once where these files are included, you can only check for files within the project if they - maybe indirectly - include a certain file. This is a big help, but not very comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

In the Project Options, enable the compiler's general messages. When the compiler encounters an error, you will be able to see the chain of includes that lead to the erroneous code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but where can I find this setting?

Comment: Tools->Options...->Environmental Options->C++ Options->Project Properties, "Show general messages"